# Is there anyone who can help me about a little advanced scss issue?

Tags: sass

```css
.c-button {
  $self: &;
  
  &#{&}--outlined.primary {
    color: yellow;
  }
  
  &#{&}--outlined.secondary {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="c-button c-button--outlined primary"><button>
<button class="c-button c-button--outlined secondary"><button>
```

As you can see above code blocks, I can style what I want. However, I want to implement it clearly. I have tried one way to implement more logical like below, but I couldn't :) If my class selector style is weird for you, I can say that ".c-button.c-button--outlined" is the same with "&#{&}--outlined"

```css
.c-button {
  $self: &;
  
  &#{&}--outlined[class*="."] {
     .primary {
        color: yellow;
     }

     .secondary {
        color: red
     }
  }

}
```

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance for your valuable time and effort

Comment: Neither `class` names, nor the `class` attribute, can contain `.`, so `[class*="."]` will never be able to match an element.

Comment: How can I match? Is there any way to write what I want

Comment: Please show minimal example HTML elements you want to match.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want to do :/ You should look again the post

Comment: Then simply add the expected, compiled CSS result to your post, rather than have us guess.

Answer (score 2):

This is the SCSS I would write for your case:

```
.c-button {
  &#{&}--outlined {
     &.primary {
        color: yellow;
     }

     &.secondary {
        color: red
     }
  }
}
```

which compiles to

```
.c-button.c-button--outlined.primary {
  color: yellow;
}

.c-button.c-button--outlined.secondary {
  color: red;
}
```